# How to drop rows from pandas data frame that contains a particular string(multiple) in a particular column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying this creating multiple dataframes to create multiple strings, but I am not able to remove strings more than 2 only thing is i wanted multiple strings to be removed.

```
data3 = data[~data.column.str.contains("remove words")]
data3 = data3[~data3.column.str.contains("remove me")]

data3.count
```

I have tried this but no good.

```
df = df[~df.column.isin(['remove words'])]
```

or

```
df = df[~df.column.isin(['remove words', 'remove me'])]
```

Comment: Please provide sample data & expected result.

Comment: I would like to get rid of strings(remove words, remove me, etc etc) from the column df.column
data = df[~df.words.str.contains("wierd")] 
data = data[~data.words.str.contains("getout")] 
data.count

words is the column in the excel sheet

Comment: You want to keep rows where the value for column `text` is not in a given list e.g. `["remove words", "remove me"]`. Is that right? Then you're on the good way, `isin()` seems like a solution. 

Please rephrase your question, and include sample data, expected result and your error.

Comment: data = df[~df.text.str.contains("getout")] 
data = data[~data.text.str.contains("wierd")] 
data.count

When i try this
df = df[~df.text.isin(['getout', 'wierd'])]

I see no changes to my df

Comment: I wanted to remove the whole row which contains the strings 'wierd' or 'getout'.
I wanted to remove it from the column named text. Any row which contains these words('wierd' or 'getout') is to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add `loc`. When a boolean mask is applied to a dataframe/series, only the explicit loc notation will do the trick.

```
df.loc[~df.column.isin(['remove words', 'remove me'])]
```

Comment: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right path.

Let's define a toy dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([("i have a car", 2), 
    ("cows make milk", 3), 
    ("try this remove me stuff", 5), 
    ("please remove words", 51)], 
    columns=["text", "number"])
```

And here you go:

```
>>> words_to_avoid = ["remove me", "remove words"]
>>> df[df.text.apply(
        lambda txt: not any([word_to_avoid in txt for word_to_avoid in words_to_avoid])
    )]

    text    number
0   car       2
1   cow       3
```

Comment: The column 'text' here is sentence. index[2] will be -  "can i remove words from the list". So if i see the remove words from the sentence I just wanted to remove the whole row. Just like this the other words.

Comment: Got it. Edited my answer. You want to remove rows where `text` contains one of the words to avoid in a given list, here called `words_to_avoid`.

Comment: Please accept the answer then. You're welcome! Next time, better than trying to describe with plain words, please attach a sample input and a sample output. That'll make it much much easier.

Comment: TypeError  argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: Accept the answer and create a new question please.

Comment: can it work on all of these "remove words", "Remove Words", "Remove words"

Comment: Yes. Use `word_to_avoid in txt.lower()` to make it case unsensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
df2 = df1[~df1.column.str.contains('remove words|remove me', regex=True)]
```